# How to make a full page auto-image-size slider for WordPress?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, slider, parallax

Any one can help me with ideas or where/how to begin in doing a full page slider that will the landing page for a wordress website, the website uses the parallax effect so when the user scrolls down this slider will be overlayed with the section below.

I can use a slider script or develop one myself, this is not the issue, what I really need help in is how to get the slider to get the browser dimensions and resize the images accordingly

something like this -> http://grovemade.com/
this website resize the image with the browser dimensions and place the menu at the bottom all the times which is pretty cool

any ideas, please?

Thanks!

Comment: You could start with [Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/ does it all for you.

Comment: I came across this and is really great, yet *shy face* I do not know how to make when the visitor scrolls down, the lower section goes above this slider not just a regular dumb scroll, any thoughts ?